Set button for input time is not displayed
Given this HTML snippet:


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chota@0.9.2/dist/chota.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<form>
  <label for="time" class="form-label">Set time</label>
  <input type="time" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" step="60" required>
</form>



Browsing the page that contains this code with Android 13 and stock browser v111.0 the time picker does not show the "Set" button:

it is impossible for the user to set the desired time.
Using other versions, even older (i.e. Android 12 and v99.0) the "Set" button is there:

Is there anything I should add to the input tag in order to allow the user to set the datetime?

   ****1.Cause of browser specific behaviour
    2.Use a custom time picker.The popular library is Flatpickr
    3.Create a button using button tag , so when we click button it shows time 
     to set****.

 

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chota@0.9.2/dist/chota.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet"/>

   <form>
   <label for="set_time" class="form-label">Set time using button</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="set_time" name="set_time" 
    required>
    <button type="button" class="buttontag" onclick="timepicker()">Set Time 
     using button</button>
     </form>

<script>
  function timepicker() {
    const input_time = document.getElementById('set_time');
    const set_time= prompt("Enter time to set (HH:MM):", "12:00");
    if (set_time) {
      input_time.value = set_time;
    }
  }
</script>

